# How to get the page name of the current view in the layout

Tags: c#, view

I was using a few different pages with exactly the same info. So I placed it all in a layout page so I don't have double code.

I have a option in de layout to change the language. When you change the language a request will be send to a controller method together with the language: "en-US" and the current page name "Index".
This method is going to execute a `RedirectResult(page)` so the language change is applied.

I was and am using this to get the name of the current file (page name):

```
@{ string pageName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Server.MapPath(VirtualPath)); }
```

First this code was standing in de Index.cshtml file, then the `pageName` would be "Index".

Now the `pageName` is "_layout". And this is giving me an error because that method clearly does not exists.

**Question:** How do I get the name of the current page from my _layout file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a longer and longer search then before this question I found something:

```
string pageName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath);
```

For more information about this:

https://forums.asp.net/t/318949.aspx?How+to+get+current+page+file+name+